# Consul KV data store http api write acquire lock and release session

Tags: api, consul

I'm using this command to store key value using session lock in Consul data store.

```
curl -X PUT -d 300 http://10.0.0.10:8500/v1/kv/my-key-value?acquire=$session
```

How can I release the lock acquired and can I do so in the same command line?

Answer (score 0):

consul kv put -release -session=sessionid my-key-value